# Why does Mathematica round numbers in this way where the fractional part is 0.5?

Tags: numerics, language-design, rounding

I was trying to comment on sequence https://oeis.org/A047229 in the OEIS, when one of the editors pointed out that the rounding is done wrong in this Mathematica one-liner:

```
Table[Round[(3*n - 3)/2], {n, 1, 57}]
```

In Mathematica I get the following results:

```
Round[1.5] = 2
Round[4.5] = 4
Round[7.5] = 8
Round[10.5] = 10
```

In school I was taught that you should round fractions equal to 0.5 up and that the correct answers are:

```
Round[1.5] = 2
Round[4.5] = 5
Round[7.5] = 8
Round[10.5] = 11
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: It is stated clearly in the documentation of `Round` that this is a feature.

Comment: someone decided long time ago to do it that way in Mathematica. Too late to change. Different CAS systems can do it differently. In Maple `round(4.5)` gives `5` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UQKYA.png), while Maxima does it like Mathematica. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BG1Wu.png)